# Intellisense not working in code snippets - VS Code

Tags: intellisense, visual-studio-code, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

I have installed the C# extension in VS Code. The problem I am having is, after using a code snippet `prop`, Intellisense no longer suggests variable types. This happens with other things like `ctor` as well, it will not autocomplete the class name, for example.

I have tried uninstalling/reinstalling the extension. I have Googled without luck as well.

I expect for Intellisense to suggest variable types, for example. Intellisense does not suggest anything.

Hitting `Ctrl+.` does suggest the correct fix among the list.

Edit: My project does not have a project.json or *.sln file. I created the project using the command line `dotnet new webapi`. If that is what is required, how do I add it or get Intellisense working?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

By default, intellisense / quick suggestions will not be triggered inside of a snippet.  To enable them set

```
"editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": false
```

`true` is the default.

`Editor > Suggest: Snippets Prevent Quick Suggestions` in the Settings UI.

Comment: this can backfire. if Intellisense suggests something and you click `tab` to go to the next snippet place, it will complete the suggestion. E.g. `for` snippet; typing `i` as variable; Intellisense suggestion:`int`; click `tab`; `int` inserted.  
But to avoid this, click `escape` before `tab` (**only if Intellisense prompted**)

Comment: @Superior Why does visual studio not have this problem? Why can't vs code provide the same experience as visual studio?

Comment: @JokeHuang Why is that question directed towards me? I don't know

Comment: @Superior isn't there a setting to enable tab to trigger the suggestion if the dropdown is displayed and go to the next snippet placeholder otherwise ?

Comment: @Gruvw yes, one posted in this answer. I just said that, to remove the dropdown, you have to click `escape`

Comment: @Superior for me, when I click tab, it does not complete the suggestion but it will go to the next snippet placeholder even though the suggestion menu is displayed

Answer (score 4):

Mark answered the question above. If he is able to come back I'll accept his answer.

File > Preferences > Settings

Search for `editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions`.

Make sure the box is unchecked.

Thanks Mark!

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error and I solved it with this configuration:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Code's more advanced editing features (IntelliSense, refactoring tools, etc.) only work in C# files if you have a project.json file or *.sln file that VSCode is aware of.

> Open the folder (i.e. open the File menu and click Open Folder...) with the *.sln file or project.json and VSCode will attempt to find all project/solution files in the folder.
>
> If there are multiple projects, you may need to select one from the projects button on the right side of the status bar (bottom of the window).

From the VSCode website:

> Selecting a project.json-file is opening a DNX-project and VSCode will load that project plus the referenced projects
>
> Selecting a *.sln-file is opening a MSBuild-project. It will load the referenced *.csproj-projects and sibling or descendant project.json-files but no other project files that are referenced from the solution file.
>
> Selecting a folder will make VSCode scan for *.sln and project.json files and VSCode will attempt to load them all.

Comment: I editing the original question. I do not have a project.json or *.sln file.

Comment: Which IntelliSense extension you are using? If not try to download Visual Studio IntelliCode