# How do you use an Emmet shortcut inside a tabstop from a VSCode Snippet?

Tags: php, html, visual-studio-code, emmet, vscode-snippets

I have created several custom User Snippets in my VSCode that I have added to the html.json file. My idea is to be able to tab and edit both inside and outside PHP tags.

One example of an if else with PHP inside HTML:

```
"Ife:": {
        "prefix": ":ife",
        "body": [
            "<?php if($1): ?>",
            "\t$2",
            "<?php else: ?>",
            "\t$3",
            "<?php endif; ?>",
            "$0"
        ],
        "description": "Ife:"
    }
```

The problem that I have encountered is that when I tab outside the PHP tags and I want to use an Emmet shortcut Emmet does not work. I can keep tabbing until I get to $0 and after that if I place the cursor back to $2 or $3 THEN I CAN USE Emmet shortcuts.

So, is it not possible to use Emmet with snippets' tabstops or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, 24 hours later I realized this is an issue of wider scope that affects to all Intellisense in general and that can be configured under:

File > Preferences > Settings

Search for `editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions`.

You guys can read further discussion here: [Intellisense not working in code snippets - VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55683145/3920354)